# Error code "-1003"

Tags: web-services, soap

What does this error mean?  I am getting it in response to a SOAP call to GetListItems.  There is no description text.

I am authenticated and can successfully call this from SPServices(), but not through a custom call I am making from iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a SP error code but a client side (iOS) error code.

Check out the following stackoverflow answers; they might help you resolve your issue:

[Undocumented NSURLErrorDomain error codes (-1001, -1003 and -1004) using StoreKit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7492235/495340)

[iPhone In-App Purchase Store Kit error -1003 “Cannot connect to iTunes Store”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4773988/495340)

Also, try connecting using a Windows OS. Do you still have this issue? If yes, then the next step is to investigate the log records on the SP server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I don't have access to the logs for this deployment, and unfortunately can't run the iOS app in Windows, but your first link had the answer in it: the hostname was incorrect (it needed a trailing slash).